# How do I find a shortcode stored in wordpress?

Tags: search

I need to find a shortcode - [shortcodename] - in WordPress. How do I do that? There doesn't seem to be a search option, which seems a bit ridiculous for a editing tool.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean find a shortcode? Find pages with that shortcode being used? Find the plugin the shortcode belongs to? Find the code for the shortcode?

Comment: @James Rickman You should elaborate your question. Do you need to search for a specific shortcode in wp-admin area that you would like to insert un the page/post content or you need to search where it is placed entire whole website?

Comment: There is a shortcode on a particular page and I would like to locate this shortcode so I can check what content it is driving. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this helps but https://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/ has a list of shortcodes available within WordPress. remember that themes may add additional codes.

I've tried to format my reply so the codes are on separate lines but can't work out how to do it. If someone could edit my answer/format it so I can learn that would be much appreciated.

**Available shortcodes**

**Video**

[dailymotion] embeds a DailyMotion video
[flickr] embeds a Flickr video
[hulu] embeds a Hulu video
[kickstarter] embeds a Kickstarter video
[ted] embeds a TED Talks video
[twitchtv] embeds a Twitch.tv stream
[ustream] embeds a Ustream.TV video
[vimeo] embeds a Vimeo video
[wpvideo] embeds a VideoPress video
[youtube] embeds a YouTube video
[archiveorg] embeds a video from The Internet Archive

**Audio**

[audio] displays uploaded audio file as an audio player
[playlist] displays a playlist for uploaded uploaded audio files
[soundcloud] embeds audio from SoundCloud
[spotify] embeds music from Spotify
[bandcamp] embeds music from Bandcamp
[8tracks] embeds music from 8tracks

**Images and Documents**

[gallery] inserts an image gallery into a post or page
[instagram] embeds an image from Instagram
[scribd] embeds a document/file from Scribd
[slideshare] embeds a slideshow from Slideshare.net
[slideshow] embeds a slideshow of uploaded photos
[presentation] embeds a slideshow presentation
[googleapps] embeds a document from Google Docs
[lytro] embeds an image from Lytro » Full instructions
[vr] embeds 360° photos and panoramas for use with VR headsets
[office] embeds documents from Microsoft Office Live

Comment: This is a list of shortcodes available on the WordPress **.com** service, which is not the same as the shortcodes bundled in WordPress itself.

Comment: The shortcode is [allvendorpartners] which is specific to my business. It was written by a developer at an agency we no longer work with.